# Vuetify: How to do a v-select search in array of arrays

Tags: arrays, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm trying to do a `v-select` with the `options` coming from my API, I have the data in an array of arrays.
[Array which I got from API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sv4R3.png)

It is supposed to be a `select` with a search because it's too many data.
Here is my code:

```
<v-select 
  :items="categoriasProduto"
  v-model="dadosProduto.id_marca"
  item-text="nome"
  item-value="id"
  label="Marca"
></v-select>
```

Script:

```
mounted() {
  const url = process.env.VUE_APP_API_URL;
  axios
    .get(`${url}marcas/`)
    .then((response) => {
      this.marcas = response.data;
      console.log(this.marcas);
    });
},
```

It's there a way to make it work in `Vue`?

Comment: please, provide read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Without sufficient info, there's very little chance to answer your question meaningfully. By the way - yes. If it's possible in JavaScript, it's possible in Vue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to include searching use `v-autocomplete`. To iterate over the lists, use `.flat`:

```js
new Vue({
  el:"#app",
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: () => ({
    categoriasProduto: [
      [
        { id:1, id_simplus:'1', nome:'nome 1' },
        { id:2, id_simplus:'2', nome:'nome 2' },
      ],
      [
        { id:3, id_simplus:'3', nome:'nome 3' },
        { id:4, id_simplus:'4', nome:'nome 4' },
      ]
    ],
    dadosProduto: { id_marca: null }
  }),
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script><link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<v-app id="app">
  {{dadosProduto.id_marca}}
  <v-autocomplete
    :items="categoriasProduto.flat()"
    v-model="dadosProduto.id_marca"
    item-text="nome"
    item-value="id"
    label="Marca"
  ></v-autocomplete>
</v-app>
```

Comment: loved that .flat()